# I wanted to implement Amazon Lex with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I have an Amazon Lex QnA bot. I have a list of intents in Lex, with Sample utterances. What I want when I send the utterances to the bot is should give me a response via API.

Like -

Send utterances via nodejs -

technical_support

API Should give a response - Please tell us in a few words how we can help.
After providing user input.

Thank you for choosing our service! We will respond to your query via email within 1 day.

I wanted to integrate this using Nodejs. I was going through the documentation. Not getting how to start.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexModelsV2.html

Answer (score 0):

```
const { LexRuntimeV2 } = require('aws-sdk');

const lexRuntimeV2 = new LexRuntimeV2();

async function sendUtterance(utterance) {
  try {
    const botId = 'YOUR_BOT_ID';
    const botAliasId = 'YOUR_BOT_ALIAS_ID';
    const localeId = 'YOUR_LOCALE_ID';
    const sessionId = 'UNIQUE_SESSION_ID';

    const params = {
      botId,
      botAliasId,
      localeId,
      sessionId,
      text: utterance,
    };

    const response = await lexRuntimeV2.recognizeText(params).promise();

    // Extract the response from the API response object
    const botResponse = response.messages[0].content;

    return botResponse;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending utterance:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

// Example usage
const utterance = 'technical_support';
sendUtterance(utterance)
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Bot response:', response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```